# Showing content from pages at different URL's (masking), possibly with .htaccess

Tags: htaccess, url, url-rewriting, masking

If I have URL's like:-

```
domain.com/category/widgets/filter/blue
domain.com/category/widgets/filter/red
```

And it is pretty difficult to reconstruct them to something like:-

```
domain.com/category/blue-widgets
domain.com/category/red-widgets
```

Is there any way at all that I can use URL rewrites or anything else with .htaccess or on the server to display the URL's as the `domain.com/category/blue-widgets` on the `domain.com/category/widgets/filter/blue` page?

I've looked into masking URL's but got nowhere and this has been something bugging me for almost 6 months now. Is there any way to achieve what I want to do?

FYI: This is a Magento website and the above process, I am wanting to implement for potentially hundreds of URL's.

## Edit

To respond to @kkugelmann's answer:-

I couldn't get your proposed `RewriteRule` to make a difference at all in the `.htaccess` file so I started testing a few things in this [.htaccess tester](http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/):-

The proposed `RewriteRule` didn't work in this tester:-

[image]

However, the following did:-

[image]

But adding any of these `RewriteRule`'s into the website's `.htaccess` file did not rewrite the URL at all...

## Edit2

By the way, if I add `[R=301,L]` to the end of the URL rewrite rule, it does actually then rewrite the rule, but of course 301 redirects it as well which is unwanted behaviour.

## Edit3

I found [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14769108/htaccess-rewrite-rule-not-working-with-magento) with the same issue... And an [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14770622/898933) that solved the problem which seemed to be something to do with using `mod_proxy` and the `[P]` tag on the rule (if I try this, the page 404's).

Answer (score 2):

You'll need mod_rewrite activated and your rewrite command should look like this:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^category/([a-zA-Z]*)-([a-zA-Z]*)$ category/$2/filter/$1^
```

[Update]

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]+)/([a-zA-Z]+)/filter/([a-zA-Z]+)$ $1/$3-$2
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I've updated my question to respond to your answer... I'm wondering if you could spare 10 minutes of your time on chat to look at this further with me please? The `RewriteRule` in the `.htaccess` just doesn't want to work for some reason but I suspect you're very close with this.

Comment: Have you enabled mod_rewrite?

Comment: The Screenshots look like you want the conversion to be vice-versa... I'll rewrite the script for you and also add a third variable for the category

Comment: Thanks but same problem as before. The `RewriteRule`'s are not taking affect in the `.htaccess`. Others are, but these ones aren't. Did you read all the above edits in the question? I'd be happy to paste the entire `.htaccess` contents if you can spare 10 mins of your time.

Comment: Could you paste the wohle .htaccess file to pastebin? I can take a look.

Comment: Sure, [here you go](http://pastebin.com/uqXpyvsN) (see line 129 for your latest entry)... Thanks.

Comment: Hey there, sorry for the silence.

I gave the .htaccess a look and there is something happening with this line

`RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]`

which rewrites the URL to url.com/-

Comment: Shall I just comment those lines out for the CGI workaround? Thanks.

Comment: You could try to comment these out if you don't need them, yeah.

Comment: And remember to activate te rewrite rule

Comment: That didn't make any difference. I commented out that entire section in `.htaccess` but the URL `RewriteRule` you suggestion didn't rewrite the rule at all. Not convinced that is the problem preventing the rules to work.

Comment: That's strange - i pasted the whole .htaccess file in the .htaccess tester and it worked for me...

Comment: can you turn on mod_rewrite logging so we can see whats happening?

Comment: It is logging, the log file is 20Gb though... Could take some time to download/open - hah. Will report back as soon as I can (will probably just rename it so that a new one is created).

Comment: You should think about log rotation - big log files are bad for the servers workload

Comment: Yes will have to consider log rotation - one reload of a page on the frontend is writing 1000+ lines to the rewrite.log :/ I've grabbed what I think is relevant and stuck it in this [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/xugqVV11).

Comment: Have you been able to figure out the problem by now?

If no: Which RewriteRule has been activated when creating this log?

Comment: Haven't managed to get this working as of yet no. None of the suggested rewrites have had any effect. The log entries were from the last RewriteRule in your updated answer `RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]+)/([a-zA-Z]+)/filter/([a-zA-Z]+)$ $1/$3-$2` Thanks